# Zend_Rss_Feed_Reader -> How to avoid exception if the feed source gets invalid?

Tags: zend-framework, rss

I had the following:

```
  $feedUrl = 'http://www.something.org/?feed=rss2';
  $feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import($feedUrl);
  $lastNews = array();
   //etc...

  return $lastNews;
```

The problem was that, if the feed didn't exist for somereason, Zend will throw an exception and all my website will stay useless with that exception message.

I end up doing like this:

```
try {
  $feedUrl = 'http://www.something.org/?feed=rss2';
  $feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import($feedUrl);
  $lastNews = array();
   //etc...

  return $lastNews;
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   return false;
}
```

It works, but I just made up this. Not sure if it's ok. Any suggestions?

Regards,
MEM

Answer (score 2):

That essentially the way you handle an Exception. Im not sure if i would return false, my preference would probably be for an empty `array` so that i dont have to have an if statement encapsulating loops that use the return value... but thats entirely up to you.

The only other exception would be to use a more specific exception like

```
try {

}
catch(Zend_Feed_Reader_Exception)
{

}
```

This way if a different error occurs you can handle it in a different fashion. Im not sure that exception actually exists but there is probably one or more exceptions unique tot he Zend_Feed component. Take a look at the code or docs to figure out which one(s) you want to catch and handle.

Comment: I agree.  I would return an empty array. If the caller is expecting an array, you should return one.  I also agree that you should try and catch the specific exception(s) that could get thrown.